# Unable to locate LInk to Item card in Flow Send an email body

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, flow

I am working on SharePoint 2013 on prem. Using an on prem gateway, I have flows setup that sends alerts out to different people. The issue I am noticing is, the 'link to item' card is missing from the list of dynamic content, I have used FLOW in SharePoint online and link to item does appear but now while working with on prem. Basically I am just trying to include a URL to SharePoint list item so users can click on the link from Email itself.

If anyone came across this, please help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that field is not available via the gateway, change the email to be html, and include a link to the item:

```
<a href='https://sharepointserver/sites/site/lists/somelist/DispForm.aspx?ID=999'>link to item</a>
```

In place of the "999", use the flow interface to insert the item id field.

Comment: Mike, thanks. This works. However, I am unable to make it href. If I use ishtml to yes then my email body gets messed up. How can I make it an href?

Comment: If you're using the original email action (with the option to change it to html), then the entire body would need to be html. So add <p>, <br/>, etc., as needed to format the email. Or, try out the new v2 email action (which is marked as being in preview), which gives a formatting toolbar and the ability to add links without hard-coding the html.

Comment: I simply put the Url to the dispform and took ID value from the data card, it works fine now. Thanks for the valuable suggestion.